# How to set Flask 'ssl_context' as an environment variable or served via a config file?

Tags: python, flask, heroku

Hoping someone can help me as I'm struggling to find the answer to this anywhere.

I'm building a Flask app which has to be run in HTTPS. In local development, I'm just doing a really quick ssl_context='adhoc' when running the app as per the below:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(
    ssl_context='adhoc',
)
```

This works perfectly but as I'm now getting ready to start testing via Heroku I'd like to change this so that the ssl_context is set in my config file:

```
import os
from decouple import config


class Config:
    DEBUG = False
    DEVELOPMENT = False
    SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')


class ProductionConfig(Config):
    pass


class StagingConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = True


class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = True
    DEVELOPMENT = True
    # Add cert here
```

I've tried using FLASK_RUN_CERT = 'adhoc' but that doesn't work and I'm stumped as to what else I can use here. I don't mind removing the ssl_context='adhoc' every time I commit but if I can avoid it that would be preferential.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you have to set ssl_context in flask? When I've done this before I would normally configure this at the last stage of deployment, i.e. get the app up and running then create a cert to enable https on the server - heroku in your case - and then force all connections to https.

Comment: Yeah I'd prefer to do that but I'm building an app fed by an API that requires HTTPS so have no other choice at the moment

Answer (score 0):

So after much digging I still could not find a way to correctly set this using environment variables.

I just used a simple if statement switch instead:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
if config('APP_SETTINGS') == "config.DevelopmentConfig":
    app.run(
        ssl_context='adhoc',
    )
else:
    app.run()
```